# EntityFramework - hitting back button and re-submitting causes errors

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using Entity Framework 4 and I have found that when I hit the back button on my browser to navigate to an earlier page that I've re-directed from then the page will open but when I re-submit its form I get all sorts of strange errors such as,

> 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

The question is how can re-submitting a form create such an error when as far as I know a new db context is created fresh with each request? I can see them being created new in the debugger!

Before the attach code's run I looked in the context to see if the entity being attached had been added and this is what it said...

> > context.Entry(entity);

```
{System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1[Entities.Orders.Order]}
CurrentValues: 'context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
Entity: {Entities.Orders.Order}
OriginalValues: 'context.Entry(entity).OriginalValues' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
State: Detached
```

Its 'Detached' so why would I get the error when attaching the entity?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: contexts arent thread safe. you arent caching this context by any chance are you? and are you disposing the context when done?

Comment: No I'm not disposing them explicitly but as I said I can see them being new'd up in the debugger.

Comment: I was at a meeting recently and someone brought up a weird issue they were having with contexts cross requests if I recall. Just to make the finalizer gods happy, wrap it in a using statement to dispose it and try again. It may not change anything but a decent starting point. Anything that implements IDisposable should be disposed. Also because they are newd up doesn't mean there isn't any static leftover info around (Im not sure of internals - just saying a new object doesn't guarantee 100% clean state - especially if behind the scenes it uses a thread context, etc)

Comment: Yes what you say sounds sensible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't say that the entity is loaded by your new context. The error says that entity thinks that it is attached to another context - probably the one from your previous request which can already be disposed. That is some bad behavior of dynamic proxies - they keep reference to the old context even if it is disposed. The only way to avoit this is either not using proxies (= not using lazy loading and dynamic change tracking) or manually detaching entities which will break the object graph (navigation properties will be null).

How can this happen? Do you store the entity somewhere (for example in the session)? Once you attached the entity to the context and then hit the back button your session contains entity which can't be attached to an another context.

Comment: Hi, I'm loading the entity in an ASP.net MVC filter and then assigning it to a controller base class. Controllers are then passing the entity to services that use a _different_ context. I appear to have gotten rid of the error by using a 'per web request' lifetime manager when injecting the context. It still seems strange though that I should only have gotten this error when pressing the back button and re-submitting instead of with normal page use.